# How to achieve this multidimensional array in the most efficient way?

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array, constructor, object-literal

I want to make this array using JavaScript:

```
    -----------------------------------------------
    |                     |         male          |
    |                     |-----------------------|
    |   rafael            |         single        |
    |                     |-----------------------|
    |                     |          22           | 
    |---------------------|-----------------------|
    |                     |         male          |
    |   jack              |-----------------------|
    |                     |         married       |      
    |                     |-----------------------|
    |                     |         34            |
    -----------------------------------------------
```

And after a lot of thinking about how to make it i just used this :

```
var arr = [];
for(i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++){
    arr[i] = [2]
    for (j = 0; j < 3 ; j++){
        arr[i][1] = [3];
        arr[i][1][j] = "this is row :" + i + ", column : 1, row : " + j ;
        console.log(arr[i][1][j]);
    }
}
```

Is there any other way, using object constructors or object literals to achieve this ?
Because i want to access it like that

```
obj["first row"]["third row in second column"]
```

I want the user to enter whatever values in each cell, and call it like this :

```
obj["rafael"]["age"];
```

**Note** that i don't know how many rows there'd be, i just put and arbitrary values there, and arbitrary cell names.

Comment: Because i want each row to have two columns.

Comment: Is each large row guaranteed to contain 3 small rows?

Comment: Yes, each second cell in each row has 3 small rows.

Comment: What do the three small rows represent?

Comment: Ok, i'll edit the question with more details on the contents.

Comment: I think we need to know, how you get the actual data from the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't make it an array, but rather an object ... since you are using it like an object anyways.  (If you aren't using integer indexes and the length property, you using the array like a basic object anyways.  All arrays are objects, not all objects are arrays.)

Replace `null` with the values you'd be using, of course.  Or you can leave them as placeholders.

```
var a = {
  "first row": {
    "first row in second column": null,
    "second row in second column": null,
    "third row in second column": null
  },
  "second row": {
    "first row in second column": null,
    "second row in second column": null,
    "third row in second column": null
  }
}
```

Ah, if it is going to be dynamic, then I'd do something like this:

```
var folk = {};  // Our basic place holder.
var person = {};  // The 'inner information' to populate.
person.married = true;
person.age = 41;
person.address = "777 Heaven's Gate";
folk["Jeremy J Starcher"] = person;

// Next person
person = {};
person.gender = 'male';
person.insurance = true;
folk["John Doe"] = person;

window.alert(folk["John Doe"]["gender"]);
window.alert(folk["John Doe"].gender);
```

Comment: But i want it to be dynamic, i don't know how many rows the user want, or the name of each key. The two rows was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access elements by string names, you'd need to use an object. Arrays only support numerical indices.

```
var data = {
    'first row': {
        'first column': 'foo',
        'second column': 'bar',
        'third column': 'baz'
    },
    'second row': {
        'first column': 'foo',
        'second column': 'bar',
        'third column': 'baz'
    }
};

data['first row']['first column']; // gives you 'foo'
```

Note that you need to quote the key names only if they have invalid indentifier characters (in this case, spaces)

Comment: But i want it to be dynamic, i don't know how many rows the user want, or the name of each key. The two rows was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

This would give you an object with dynamic properties:

```
var arr = new Object();
for(i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++){
    var rowName = "row"+i;
    arr[rowName] = new Object();
    for (j = 0; j < 3 ; j++){
        var colName = "col"+j;
        arr[rowName][colName] = "this is row " + i + ", column " + j;
    }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would map your data to cells with:

```
    -----------------------------------------------
    | arr[0].left         | arr[0].right[0]       |
    |                     |-----------------------|
    |                     | arr[0].right[1]       |
    |                     |-----------------------|
    |                     | arr[0].right[2]       | 
    -----------------------------------------------
    | arr[1].left         | arr[1].right[0]       |
    |                     |-----------------------|
    |                     | arr[1].right[1]       |
    |                     |-----------------------|
    |                     | arr[1].right[2]       | 
    -----------------------------------------------
```

You can do that with:

```
var arr = []

for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    arr[i] = {
        left: "someText",
        right: [
            "some",
            "more",
            "text"
        ]
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your edits, you either want:

```
var data = {
    rafael: {
        gender: "male",
        status: "single",
        age: "22"
    },
    jack: {
        gender: "male",
        status: "married",
        age: "34"
    }
};
```

or

```
var data = [{
    name: "rafael",
    gender: "male",
    status: "single",
    age: "22"
}, {
    name: "jack",
    gender: "male",
    status: "married",
    age: "34"
}];
```

Comment: In your first example, can i make the most outer object i.e `data` dynamic ? i mean the user can enter a new data to it, like example `mark` ?